# Marshalling argument exception

Tags: java

The server starts fine, but the error occurs
when I try to add any job from the Client. I get the
following error

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception
is: 

    java.io.NotSerializableException: snaq.db.CacheConnection
    at Production_Stub.addGRN(Production_Stub.java:1515)
    at ProductionServices.addGRN(ProductionServices.java:21)
    at PlanningServices.addGRN(PlanningServices.java:22)
    at Planning.addtoGrn(Planning.java:9949)
    at Planning.saveAllBundleRelatedTables(Planning.java:9582)
    at Planning.savebundlesheet(Planning.java:9251)
    at Planning_Skel.dispatch(Planning_Skel.java:6555)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:207)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:148)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:144)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:460)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:701)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:534)
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: snaq.db.CacheConnection
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1059)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:278)
    at Production_Stub.addGRN(Production_Stub.java:1513)
    ... 14 more
```

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on here is that one of the object that you are trying to send over RMI is an instance of the class `snaq.db.CacheConnection`, or (more likely) contains a reference to one somewhere.

This ain't going to work.  The `CacheConnection` class is not serializable, and there's a good chance that cannot be made serializable.

A possible cure for this is to mark the field (or fields) of type CacheConnection in the classes you are trying to send as `transient`.